# Warning: date_default_timezone_get() installing Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to install Symfony on XAMPP and I keep getting numerous errors.

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.
You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.
In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set 
date.timezone to select your timezone. in 
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php line 233
```

and then

```
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-
install-cmd event terminated with an exception
```

and finally

```
[RuntimeException]                                                         
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

I've tried changing the date.timezone in my php.ini file and using the date_default_timezone_set() function in the command line before trying to install it and nothing seems to work.

I've been staring at it for a while so any help is appreciated

Comment: first one explains *exactly* what you need to do

Comment: Does this [Github bug Help](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5893)?

Comment: @dabecks: read it once again thoroughly and try again, because it does work.

Comment: @dagon I've tried doing going into that file as well and setting the default timezone on line 233 but that doesn't work either

Comment: @dabecks: it does work for everyone but you. Thoughts?

Comment: it doesn't work for me either zerkms.  i've successfully set up several projects in my enviroment with 2.3 and everything is configured correctly but i'm getting this bug with SF 2.5

Answer (score 29):

If you can't set it correctly in your `php.ini` for some reason then you can set it as the first thing in your AppKernel, like so..

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function __construct($environment, $debug)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
        parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
    }

    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            ....
        );
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but @Pknife's solution, which also worked, is cleaner

Comment: This is an alternative "if you can't set it correctly in your php.ini for some reason". I would always recommend the `php.ini` approach if it is available to you.

Comment: It's not a problem, it's good to get feedback. The main disadvantage with doing it my way is that if you were to host in a different timezone you would need to update the code. It's not the cleanest approach but when life give you lemons you set the timezone in the AppKernel.

Comment: @qooplmao Where do I find AppKernel file?

Comment: In the `app` directory. It's the file that you add all of the registered bundles to.

Answer (score 22):

Found a similar way to fix this issue while other didn't.

1. First check where the CLI php.ini is located:

   `php -i | grep "php.ini"`
2. In my case I ended up with : Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
3. Then `cd ..` all the way back and `cd` into `/etc`, do `ls` in my case php.ini didn't show up, only a `php.ini.default`
4. Now, copy the php.ini.default file named as php.ini:

   `sudo cp php.ini.default php.ini`
5. In order to edit, change the permissions of the file:

   `sudo chmod ug+w php.ini`

   `sudo chgrp staff php.ini`
6. Open directory and edit the php.ini file:

   `open .`

   *Tip: If you are not able to edit the php.ini due to some permissions issue then copy 'php.ini.default' and paste it on your desktop and rename it to 'php.ini' then open it and edit it following step 7. Then move (copy+paste) it in /etc folder. Issue will be resolved.*
7. Search for [Date] and make sure the following line is in the correct format:

   `date.timezone = "Europe/Amsterdam"`

Comment: This did not seem to fix the issue.  I verified php.ini I edited was correct by running phpinfo() and seeing the path for the .ini file was the same.  Seems like the only fix is the one above.

Comment: @JosephAstrahan, did you restart the apache service afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

It is very very common for `WAMP`/`XAMPP` and other stacks to have use of multiple `php.ini` files - one for cli and one for web.

Since you're expiriencing the error from CLI try the following:

```
php -i | grep "php.ini"
```

this will output location of `php.ini` used for cli. Edit the `date.timezone` there.

As for the web mode, create a file `foo.php` within your "web" directory of symfony containing only"

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And, again, find the location of `php.ini` used and edit the `date.timezone`.

Answer (score 3):

Edit your `php.ini` (not necessarily at `/etc/php.ini` - use `php -i | grep ini` to find your version) and add your timezone.

E.g. for America / New York it would be:

```
date.timezone = "America/New_York"
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

Answer (score 0):

It's been mentioned but this is as simple as:

sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini

You can't set the timezone if it can't find the php.ini file!!!!