# Symfony - MAMP(windows) - warning timezone

Tags: php, symfony, timezone, mamp, ini

I installed MAMP for windows

I have this error since several hours...

```
    [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                   
 Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system' 
 s timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or 
  the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those me 
 thods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled th 
 e timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please s 
 et date.timezone to select your timezone.
```

In the `php.ini` concerned (C:/MAMP/conf/php5.5.19/php.ini), I changed the line DATE like this:

```
    [Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
date.timezone = "Europe/Paris"
```

And in my `phpinfo()`, the path loaded is :

```
Loaded Configuration File   C:\MAMP\conf\php5.5.19\php.ini
```

When I do in the consol the command `php --ini` I have this :

```
C:\Users\Thomas>php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File: (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Why  `Configuration File (php.ini) Path:` is `"C:\Windows"` and not `C:\MAMP\conf\php5.5.19\`. Can I change this Path ?

I don't know what to do now...

thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: date\_default\_timezone\_get() installing Symfony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251793/warning-date-default-timezone-get-installing-symfony)

Comment: Did you restart the apache server after the changes ?

Comment: @Brewal : I follow instructions but nothing to do. And yes I restarded apache server with MAMP.

Comment: The error hes getting is for the CLI php, not the Webserver so restarting Apache would have no bearing. Are you sure you are accessing the correct PHP binary?

Comment: @prodigitalson : How to do for know that ?

Comment: @Zagloo Can you precise from where the `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]` error comes from ?

Comment: Try running `where php` from the command line... i think that should work. Not really a windows guy... :-/

Comment: @Brewal : In the Command Line Tools Console in PhpStorm when I do "doctrine:schema:update" or whatever

Comment: @prodigitalson : the result of  `where php` is `C:\MAMP\bin\php\php5.5.19\php.exe`

Comment: Oh youre trying to do this from your IDE.... Did you set up the IDE to use the MAMP php binary? https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-local-php-interpreters.html

Comment: @prodigitalson yes  I did

Comment: Hmm... no clue then. Normally the ini location to search is set when PHP is compiled, so i would expect that the MAMP team would change this from the default `C:\Windows` to `C:\MAMP\conf\php5.5.19\` or what have you or otherwise deploy their configuration to `C:\Windows` in some way.

Comment: @prodigitalson : I found this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844641/how-to-change-the-path-to-php-ini-in-php-cli-version . Do you think it can be a good solution ?

Comment: The PHPRC route... sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error. I had no clue where it was coming from, but with some trial and error I figured out it had something to do with the special character in my htdocs folder:

htdocs/Exámple

By changing that character to a normal character (thus changing to htdocs/Example), I no longer got the error and the site would load normally.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your xAMP server and cli access uses different php configuration.

One is C:\Windows\php.ini for CLI
Second is C:\MAMP\conf\php5.5.19\php.ini for web server

Make sure you have updated both files.

Secondly do not forget to restart xAMP server, as apache do not reload libapache2-mod-php5 configs automatically.

Answer (score 0):

When you set configuration in MAMP it only affects PHP which is loaded in Apache module handler mode (mapped as module inside Apache process). If you want to set PHP CLI you need to set this separately from web server configuration.

- Open command prompt from Windows (cmd.exe from Start button)
- enter ECHO %PATH%
- this command will list your current PATH variable with all paths. For example, something like this:

  C:>echo %PATH%

  C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\binaries\php\php_runningversion
  ;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin
  ...
- now enter following command

  SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\mamp\bin\php\php5.6.0\;

This will going to add path to php5.6.0 version from MAMP folder.

- you can now test your PHP CLI by entering following command :

  php -v
- then try to initialize configuration from MAMP for version PHP5.6.0 file:

  C:>php -c "c:\mamp\conf\php5.6.0\php.ini" --ini

  Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
  Loaded Configuration File:         C:\MAMP\conf\php5.6.0\php.ini
  Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
  Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

You can use command -c from PHP CLI to set path to configuration file; and "c:\mamp\conf\php5.6.0\php.ini" is path to PHP ini file for version 5.6.0.

If you do not want to always add path to configuration file with -c command, just copy php.ini file from C:\MAMP\conf\php5.6.0\ to C:\MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.0\

Off course, this will going to set PHP CLI only in currently opened command prompt. To add this path permanently, you need to modify System Environment variable, or to use MAMP PRO as it already have this feature on PHP options page.

Answer (score 0):

**TL:DR** - Make sure to edit both the `..\MAMPPRO\conf\php[version].ini` and the `..\MAMP\bin\php\php[version]\php.ini` with your correct/approved php timezone.

---

So while I was going through my setup, I had the same issue.

I was taking a look at my phpinfo() and it was giving me a path to my "Loaded Configuration File" that was located in my `..\MAMPPRO\conf\php[version].ini` so I was editing that file with approved timezone from http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php making sure to avoid any from http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php.

After a few restarts and no success I started to dig a little further into where MAMP Pro was pulling that ini.

I found the solution in `..\MAMP\bin\php\php[version]\php.ini`. If I edited this file **IN ADDITION TO** editing the MAMP Pro ini everything worked properly.

Hopefully this can help you out!

Answer (score -1):

At the beggining of your web/app_dev.php and web/app.php you can add:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
```

Comment: Chances are this is happening when trying to create the new symfony project file. This answer does not fix the error, it just bypasses it.