# Symfony 2.7: default timezone not set, causing fatal error

Tags: php, symfony, timezone, server

I'm trying to set up a **symfony 2.7** based app on a **shared server** and have **no permission** to change the **php.ini**.

Executing: `php app/console doctrine:schema:drop --force`

Outputs this warnings/errors:

```
PHP Warning:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException' with message 'Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.'
0 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler-    >handleError(2, 'date_default_ti...', '/path...', 272, Array)
1 /domain.com/app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(272): date_default_timezone_get()
2 /domain.com/app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(481): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(100, 'Notified event ...', Array)
3 /domain.com/app/vendor/symfony/ in /domain.com/app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php on line 272
PHP Fatal error:  date_default_timezone_get(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen! in /domain.com/app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php on line 272
PHP Warning:  date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /domain.com/app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php on line 272
PHP Fatal error:  date_default_timezone_get(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen! in /domain.com
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743060/symfony2-and-date-default-timezone-get-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-system):

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function init()
    {
        date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Berlin' );
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

Outputs the next error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException' with message 'Notice: date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID 'Europe/Berlin' is invalid' in /domain.com/app/app/AppKernel.php:42
```

According to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/timezones.europe.php) `Europe/Berlin` is a valid identifier.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762608/setting-default-timezone-does-not-work-despite-timezone-being-valid) `timezonedb.so` should be installed (it's not).

According to [Symfony 1.4 docs](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/04-Settings#chapter_04_sub_default_timezone) it's possible to set `default_timezone` in the `settings.yml`. I cannot find a similar config for `>= 2.0`. 
**Edit**: *"Unlike Symfony 1.4, there isn’t a default_timezone config parameter to set the default timezone in Symfony2. [...]"* ([source](http://dploy.in/2012/setting-the-default-timezone-symfony2/))

Any ideas, how to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message arises because the default timezone has not been set in the php.ini file. Please have a look at this answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251793/warning-date-default-timezone-get-installing-symfony

Comment: @Praveesh as mentioned above, I tried this solution already and I'm unfortunately still not allowed to edit the php.ini.

Comment: Simply change your hoster.

Comment: @Paziツ I'm trying to avoid it, but I guess, that's the only solution.

Comment: That's the best solution. A hoster which is such restricting it not worth the trouble..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

it is recommended that you set the timezone in php.ini but if you are in shared environment or if you don't have access to it for some reason you can add this in `app/AppKernel.php`

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
        public function __construct($environment, $debug)
        {
            date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Detroit' );
            parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
        }
}
```

Comment: Or add the same line to web/app.php

Answer (score 1):

At less for me @wonde answer didn't work i don't know why, this worked for me

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Berlin');
```

Adding this line in your files :

/web/app_dev.php

/web/app.php

and if that doesnt work add in your kernel too.

That fix the problem for me !